# Wi-Fi hub? wi-fi router as a hub?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I think that's what I want, but I can't seem to figure out the right Google term.  My problem is that we have acquired a number of wi-fi devices and have friends come by with wi-fi devices and there is insufficient reception in our living room.  Even a wi-fi booster was unable to help.  Because I have a wired star topology, I don't want to move the router to the living room.  (I'd have to add another ethernet cable back to the attic to do that anyway.)  I could use two routers, but then I have two subnets and my printer and LAN storage would be on one or the other subnet.

Shorter description:

I have a hub in the living room now and all the wired devices are using the router's dhcp to get connected.  Is there such a thing as a hub that does wi-fi, too?  What do you call such a thing?  It isn't "wi-fi hub" and there is no obvious (to me) configuration of my spare routers that wind up getting them to act like such a beast.

I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: You should look at those devices that carry a signal through the wiring in your house, rather than wifi if wifi signals aren't strong enough. I had a similar problem, upgraded, and have MUCH faster speeds. You could also hook up the router on the other end if wifi is a must.

Comment: iPad and Kindle do not even _have_ a wired connection, and I have guests who want to use WiFi on their cells.  It seems my old routers, however, do not support "access point mode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of two wireless routers (or one if it supports being in AP and bridge mode, [as explained here](http://www.tp-link.us/article/?faqid=178)). One would be in bridge mode and the other would be linked to the router and function as an access point. So you'd have something like:

`Regular AP ))) Bridge AP-->Regular AP )))` ...sorry about the bad representation, but the `)))` represents wireless, `-->` is wired.

Edit: You can also use a repeater to good effect that essentially acts as a wireless "switch" and does much like a bridge/ap combo would do.

Comment: The magic phrase I needed was "wireless access point", but setting up one of my old wireless routers in "bridge mode" is a new phrase, too.  So if bridge mode can't be gotten to work, I need to look for a "wireless access point"!  Thank you.

Comment: Desired config:  Modem --> Router --> Bridged Router AP ))) devices